# Symfony 2.4 create form through a service

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 2.4, I want to create a registration form through a service. I played around with the service configuration and the form components factories but everytime i got the following exception:

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface, instance of Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType given

code as follow:

```
services:
bestxtech.form.type.registration:
    class: Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    arguments: [null]
    tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: registration }
    public: flase
bestxtech.form.registration:
    factory-method: create
    factory-service: form.factory
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    arguments: ["@bestxtech.form.type.registration"]
```

RegistrationType as

```
//Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
<?php
namespace Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type'            => 'password',
            'first_options'   => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options'  => array('label' => 'Confirm password'),
            'invalid_message' => 'Password mismatch'
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email address'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'       => 'Bestxtech\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('Registration')
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Would be nice if someone can give me some advice, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your form factory service definition is wrong. Try to look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html.

But. Are you sure it is good idea? Pay attention that `create` method from `FormFactory` takes two additional arguments: `$data` and `$options`. If you define building your form as you've showed you won't be able to pass these arguments to `create` method.

I would use `form.factory` service directly if I was you. Like this:

```
$formFactory = $container->get('form.factory');
$form = $formFactory->create($container->get('form.type.registration'));
```

**edit:**

The problem was you've used dashes instead of underscores, try below:

```
services:
    bestxtech.form.type.registration:
        class: Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        arguments: [null]
        tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: registration }
        public: flase
    bestxtech.form.registration:
        factory_method: create
        factory_service: form.factory
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments: ["@bestxtech.form.type.registration"]
```

Comment: Could you show me with a correct service definition. I try to edit like this:

    parameters:
        bestxtech.form.type.registration.class: Bestxtech\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    services:
        bestxtech.form.registration:
        factory-method: create
        factory-service: form.factory
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments: [%bestxtech.form.type.registration.class%]

but i still the following exception:

    Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface, string given

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now a new bug comes out. I'm trying to fix it.